# how to use AWK to merge two columns from each of 10 files

Tags: awk, merge

I have 10 files that have the same tab-delimited column structure. I need to merge the columns 8 and 9 from each of the files. I came up with the following AWK code, but it only merge two files at a time. I am looking for help with merging all 10 files same time, I am not sure if this is feasible.

All my file names following the same pattern (s1s2.txt, s3s4.txt, s5s6.txt, .... s19s20.txt)

```
#!/bin/bash

awk '
 BEGIN {
        #load array with contents of the first file
        while ( getline < "s1s2.txt" > 0)
         {
           s1s2_counter++
           f1_8[s1s2_counter] = $8
           f1_9[s1s2_counter] = $9
         }
}
   {OFS="\t"}

   { #output the columns 8 and 9 from the first file before the second file
    print f1_8[NR],f1_9[NR], $8, $9
   } ' s3s4.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk -F'\t' '{a[FNR] = a[FNR] (NR==FNR?"":FS) $8 FS $9} END{for (i=1;i<=FNR;i++) print a[i]}' s1s2.txt .... s19s20.txt
```

Using getline is usually the wrong approach, see http://awk.info/?tip/getline.

Comment: You're welcome. If/when you're happy with this or any other answer you get, remember to click on the check mark next to that answer so others don't waste their time trying to come up with alternatives for you.

Comment: @user2228325 at SO you say thanks by upvoting/accepting his answer. don't forget doing it if it solved your problem.